# c# com object configuration best practice

Tags: .net, com, legacy

I have to develop extension for legacy application that relies on com objects.

My extension is implemented as com-server-in-dll (.net assembly) with MSVS and installed in [program files][company] folder (distributed as msi file).

What is the best practice to configure that: put app.config to installation folder (i suspect there would be some mess to upload that as host process has no app.config at all) or keep old days practice to deal with system registry?

What would you personally prefer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your application is hosted by a "legacy" application that uses registry-style configuration, I'd stick with that.

In particular, figuring out where to put an `app.config` might get confusing to you (as a developer) and your users. Worse, this is a different way from what anyone else coming to maintain the application in future would expect.

Comment: I have to agree... It's better to follow one way to maintain application after all...